# UICollectionViewCell layout margins never update

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which basically appears like a table, it has a horizontal stack of `UICollectionViewCell` views. I want the standard `UIViewController` layout margins (16pt on the left and right on an iPhone X) to apply to the contents of the cells. This happens in a `UITableView`.

For some reason my cells initialise with the out of the box margins (8pts) and never update.

[image: Interface Builder]

I have checked all these options in my cell's .xib, and can log out the `layoutMargins` property to reveal that the value is correct, but the subviews just never move.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that, although you can't see it in Interface Builder, a `UICollectionViewCell` has a content view, which does not by default inherit layout margins.

This solved it for me:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = YES;
    ...
}
```

Be careful on devices/views with safe area insets set, this may knock around the bottom insets of your cell.